# Is the treatment of accented 5ths and octaves in 3rd species counterpoint the same as between soprano and bass in 4 part writing?

Tags: voice-leading, species-counterpoint

Here in this image from my textbook "Harmony and voice leading" there are several very useful examples of accented and unaccented octaves and 5ths in third species Counterpoint. It shows what would be allowed and what not in 3rd species. Would this also apply in full 4 voice part writing between the base and soprano voice or would the presence of other voices in 4 part writing make some of these restrictions permissable?
[image]

Comment: I don't know for sure what the "official" rules are, but I would think that the same rules apply. In a 4-voice context, the bass and soprano are the most important voices because they are the easiest for the ear to follow, so any rule violations will be audible despite there being inner voices present. I think. And, I think this would be the case regardless of whether the texture is polyphonic or homophonic. Don't quote me.

Comment: Also, the word "leap" in the question title doesn't make sense to me.  The question is about parallel perfect consonances.  Consider editing.